# how to use EXPECT_EQ for user defined type

Tags: c++, googletest

I wanted to test a function which returns some user defined type value. I knew that I can test basic int, float, double etc with `EXPECT_EQ`, `EXPECT_FLOAT_EQ` etc but not for user defined type. any clue?

Comment: Seeing how it'll just do something like (val1 == val2) you can just override the == operator for your user defined type value.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There must be some way to check something.

---

a) return type is a data structure, where you can check the values of it's member variables :

```
struct A {
  int v1;
  float v2;
  char v4;
};
```

Then use `EXPECT_EQ`, `EXPECT_FLOAT_EQ` and available macros :

```
A a1{ 3, 2.2, 'a' };
A a2{ 4, 2.5, 'b' };
EXPECT_EQ( a1.v1, a2.v2 );
```

or even check like this if POD :

```
EXPECT_TRUE( 0 == std::memcmp( &a1, &a2, sizeof(a1) ) );
```

---

b) the return type has `operator==` implemented :

```
bool operator==( const A& lh, const A& rh ) {
    return std::make_tuple( lh.v1, lh.v2, lh.v4 ) == std::make_tuple( rh.v1, rh.v2, rh.v4 );
}
```

Then compare with `EXPECT_EQ` :

```
A a1{ 3, 2.2, 'a' };
A a2{ 4, 2.5, 'b' };
EXPECT_EQ( a1, a2 );
```

or with `EXPECT_TRUE` :

```
EXPECT_TRUE( a1 == a2 );
```

Comment: I think you meant 'operator =='

Answer (score 4):

Override the == operator. :)

```
class Object
{
public:
    bool operator==(const Object& other) const
    {
        return (this->member == other.member); // Modify this depending on the equality criteria
    }
private:
    int member;
}
```

On the test part:

```
Object a, b;
EXPECT_EQ(a, b); // Should work
```